# Finding name and details of a database

Tags: python, flask

I am new to Flask.

I have a task to connect a PostgreSQL database to my Flask app and create some API endpoints.

All the details I have on the database are the following:

- Database location: postgres://candidate.company.org/company
- Username: interview
- Password: cake

To connect to the database I did the following:

**myproject/myapp.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgres://interview:cake@candidate.company.org/suade'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

I think it is connected (how can I be sure it is connected?).

My problem is that in the task it is not written what the database contains or what the name of tables are.

How can I find out the name and content of the tables in the database if I do not know anything about it?

Answer (score 0):

Try query something like: `db.session.query("1").from_statement("SELECT 1").all()`

Comment: I am getting: `sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Textual SQL expression 'SELECT 1' should be explicitly declared as text('SELECT 1')`

Comment: try this: `db.session.query("1").from_statement(text("SELECT 1")).all()`

Comment: I get the message `x = db.session.query("1").from_statement(text("SELECT 1")).all()
NameError: name 'text' is not defined`